# Facebook Api(New launch)(IN ANDROID SDK)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

1. Is it possible to count the number of friends that make comments? (one friend makes 5 comments and other makes 3 comments in a post --> total commenters: 2)
2. Is it possible count the number of followers of a facebook page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, use the comments endpoint and go through all entries with your favourite programming language
2. Yes, but they are not followers but fans. For example, this would be an the API call: `https://graph.facebook.com/bladauhu?fields=name,likes&access_token=xxx`

You can NOT get the followers of a User Profile, only the number of fans of a Facebook Page.

More information about all endpoints: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/

Comment: Is it possible to get clear count for like comment and share of a post ? I want to code this in android ? is it possible ?

Comment: you can only get the number, not the "number per user". that´s totally up to you to program.

Comment: I can program in a way but I just want to know the feasibility as per new norms by Facebook.